# How to configure Woodstox properties in using Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, stax, woodstox

According to woodstox github https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox/issues/59

Woodstox properties can be configured through XMLInputFactory.

I'm now using camel with JAVA DSL, which use woodstox-core for XML
https://camel.apache.org/components/next/eips/split-eip.html#_streaming_big_xml_payloads_using_xml_tokenize_language

I want to configure Woodstox property e.g. `WstxInputProperties.P_RETURN_NULL_FOR_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE`

How can I configure Woodstox properties in using Apache Camel?

(Java 8, Apache Camel 2.25.4)

Code for reference:

```
camel:

        Exchange in = camelContext.getEndpoint("direct:xxx").createExchange();
        in.getIn().setBody(xmlContent);
        ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
        Exchange out = template.send("direct:xxx", in);
---
route builder:

        from("direct:xxx")
                .routeId("xxx")
                .split(body().xtokenize("//xxx:xxx", 'i', ns), myAggregationStrategy)
                    .process(myProcessor)
                .end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reported this bug to Apache. As camel 2.25.4 is already EOL, it will be fixed at new version of camel-stax.

Fix Version/s:
3.14.9, 3.18.8, 3.20.6, 3.21.0, 4.0-RC1, 4.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-19415

If it is not possible to upgrade the camel version, instead of using xml default namespace, adding a custom namespace on all xml tag should be a possible way to avoid this issue. i.e.

```
<ns1:XX ... xmlns:ns1="XXXX">
    <ns1:YY>zzz</ns1:YY>
</ns1:XX>
```